# Do sperm that carry male chromosomes swim faster?

Tags: biology, human-reproduction, gender-selection

The claim is that human sperm has different physical characteristics (i.e. phenotype) depending on whether it is carrying an X or Y chromosome.

> - One theory is that sperm that carry the male chromosome are tiny and fragile but very quick, whereas the female sperm are larger and hardier, but rather sluggish.
>     [Source](http://www.ivillage.com/gender-selection-how-to-influence/6-n-145504#ixzz1mBL0bLWs)
> - The male sperm are FAST... but die faster also. The female sperm are slow and steady and have a longer life span.
>     [Source](http://community.babycenter.com/post/a1655455/male_sperm_vs_female_sperm_os)
> - The X sperm (which are the sperm that make females) live longer than the Y sperm (which are the sperm that make males). However, the Y sperm swim faster, so the chances are equally good that you will get a girl or a boy. [Source](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Do_sperm_for_girls_live_longer)

None of these sources provide references.

Do "male" sperm swim faster than "female" sperm?

Comment: **Note**: this question was asked as part of the "[topic of the week](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/topic-of-the-week-weapons)" initiative to raise our questions per day stat. Please contribute some great questions!

Comment: I read this question title several times because I was wondering what you meant by swimming chromosomes that are carrying sperm. the title is actually fine (leave it!) but it still tripped me up.

Comment: @Konrad, I changed the title, partly because I remember as a kid being bewildered by "cat-chasing dogs" from a [children's book](http://www.earlymoments.com/Dr-Seuss--His-Friends-Club/List-of-Dr-Seuss-books1/The-King-The-Mice-And-The-Cheese/) I owned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image: XY] <sup>[Source](http://www.pc.maricopa.edu/Biology/pfinkenstadt/BIO202/202LessonBuilder/Reproductive/index.html)</sup>

A famous method for gender selection is the [Shettles Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shettles_Method), which makes use of the

> "*male (Y) sperm are faster than female (X) sperm* "

theory.

But according to **[Entrenched misinformation about X and Y sperm](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1440662/)** (2006):

> **The widely held idea that spermatozoa bearing the Y chromosome (Y
> sperm) swim faster than those bearing the X chromosome (X sperm) seems
> to have originated from [Shettles's work in 1960](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14445926)**, using phase-contrast
> microscopy.
>
> Reading Shettles's reports in *Nature* and other peer reviewed journals,
> many researchers thereafter believed that Y sperm swim faster than X
> sperm. The finding particularly influenced research on sperm
> separation.
>
> Although several attempts have been made to correct this impression,
> it was not until the development of computer assisted sperm analysis
> ([CASA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3384107)) that reliable observations could be made.
>
> So far, researchers
> have [found no morphological differences between human X sperm and Y
> sperm](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11191075).
>
> **Neither mature sperm nor their precursors possess significant
> morphological differences between X and Y genotypes**;

**More:**

- [Y bull sperm do not swim faster than X sperm](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9621308)
- [Dimensional assessment of X-bearing and Y-bearing haploid and disomic human sperm](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16412741)

Comment: Nice! I was half-expecting an answer that said "Yes, they are slightly faster, but not enough to make the Shettles(*) method effective." (*I didn't know its name.) This is even better!

Comment: I feel like the study you heavily quoted doesn't really refute the claim.  The sperm could be morphologically the same, but if the Y chromosomes had less mass, it stands to reason to me that given the same morphological structures, the Y sperm could achieve greater speed, because it has less mass to move, and the same structures to move itself.  I would think focusing on the study "Y bull sperm do not swim faster than X sperm" would make more sense.