# Can biorhythms and pH fluctuations be used to select the gender of a child?

Tags: human-reproduction, gender-selection

Smart Stork claim to be able to help couples select the gender of their future child:

> Our success rate in gender selection? Is still over 95%!

Their technique relies of biorhythms:

> Smart Storks unique gender selection program, is based primarily on a womans biorhythm  cycle and the alternating pH of acidic and alkaline fractions within her reproductive  tract, these fluctuations directly affect the gender baby that can be conceived at the time of ovulation. The biorhythm theory is a theory based on the fact that every person, from the 
>   moment of birth, is ruled by their biorhythms or circadian rhythms. It rules the balance of our 
>   sleep/awake body clock and is the basis of our hormone secretions.
>
> Our research focused on the impact of the women’s biorhythm cycles and her hormone production, the alternating pH within the follicular fluid and how that was a major factor in determining the baby’s gender at the time of ovulation.

The idea that a baby's gender is determined at ovulation, rather than conception, is a new one to me.

Their claims are (allegedly) [supported by dozens of references](http://www.smartstork.com/page23.asp).

Can techniques such as these be used with 95% reliability to select the gender of a yet-to-be-conceived child?

Comment: **Note**: this question was asked as part of the "[topic of the week](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/topic-of-the-week-weapons)" initiative to raise our questions per day stat. Please contribute some great questions!

Comment: I think that the idea of `The idea that a baby's gender is determined at ovulation, rather than conception, is a new one to me.` has to do with sperm motility, and where fertilization may happen as a result of ovulation as opposed to the ova itself.

Comment: @Brightblades: Oh! So it accidentally ties into my [other question about gender-selection](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/do-sperm-that-carry-male-chromosomes-swim-faster). I didn't intend/expect that.

Comment: Regarding biorhythm cycle, scientists believe that the idea has no more predictive power than chance and consider the concept an example of pseudoscience. An examination of some 134 biorhythm studies found that the theory is not valid-http://www.amsciepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pr0.1998.83.1.19?journalCode=pr0 and also read more here-http://skepdic.com/biorhyth.html.

Comment: @pericles316: If that is an answer, please use the answer box.

Answer (score 4):

The woman's **biorhythm cycle** which is the primary basis for Smart Storks unique gender selection program is described by scientists to be [**pseudoscience**](http://skepdic.com/biorhyth.html) and also **an examination of 134 biorhythm studies** in [1998](http://www.amsciepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pr0.1998.83.1.19?journalCode=pr0) **found that the theory is not valid.**